# Comparing two images and returning the max one as a result

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have two images such that `V1 = v*v'` and `V2 = v1*v1'`. `v` and `v1` are two matrices and `v'` and `v1'` are their transposes.

I need to compare `V1` and `V2` and select the maximum.  Specifically, whichever matrix has the maximum amount of intensity values, this is what I need to return.  How could this be done in MATLAB?

Comment: What is your definition of the "max" one?  This is very ambiguous.  Do you want to compare on an entry by entry basis, or do you want to compute a unified measure for the entire matrix?

Comment: Great, so that gets us probably 2 mm closer.  What is your definition of the "max" one?

Comment: matrix with max intensity values

Comment: So are your matrices images?

Comment: yes, they are images

Comment: Ok.  That makes more sense.  I've written an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you consider to use a norm, it is at least unconventional to make matrix comparisons such as V1 > V2. `norm(V1) > norm(V2)` would eventually do the job for you. Note that `norm` defaults to the L2 norm.

Answer (score 0):

Given your comments, an alternative could be to do this:

```
V1_max = sum(abs(V1(:));
V2_max = sum(abs(V2(:));
```

We would find the summation of all entries in `V1` as well as `V2` and see whether one is greater than the other, so `V1_max > V2_max`.

Given that you said "intensity", I'm assuming your matrices are images, and so there won't be a need to use `abs` to account for negative values.  What you should do instead is cast the images to `double` so that you can accumulate values beyond the maximum defined for the precision of your image.  For example, if your image was 8-bit, then you won't be able to accumulate values beyond 255.  Therefore, you would do something like this instead:

```
V1_max = sum(im2double(V1(:)));
V2_max = sum(im2double(V2(:)));
```